# Difference between "hbox group" and "adjusted hbox group"?

Tags: tex-core, grouping

eTeX's `\currentgrouptype` distinguishes two types of `\hbox` group types

```
\hbox{\showthe\currentgrouptype} % 3 "adjusted hbox group"
\noindent
\hbox{\showthe\currentgrouptype} % 2 "hbox group"
```

Looking at [`tex.web`](http://www.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web), I see a couple of places where `hbox_group` occurs:

```
@d hbox_group=2 {code for `\.{\\hbox}\grp'}
@d adjusted_hbox_group=3 {code for `\.{\\hbox}\grp' in vertical mode}

@<Initiate the construction of an hbox or vbox, then |return|@>=
...
  if (box_context<box_flag)and(abs(mode)=vmode) then
    scan_spec(adjusted_hbox_group,true)
  else scan_spec(hbox_group,true)

@<Cases of |handle...@>=
hbox_group: package(0);
adjusted_hbox_group: begin adjust_tail:=adjust_head; package(0);
  end;
```

I don't understand what `adjust_tail:=adjust_head` does.  Perhaps something to do with the `\vadjust` command?

Comment: Indeed I get currengrouptype=3 when I say `\vadjust{\hbox{\showthe\currentgrouptype}}`

Comment: @egreg you get this simply because the inner pert of `\vadjust` is processed in vertical mode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whenever TeX starts a new level of grouping it records the current type of group so that it can do the right kind of action if a group ends. If hboxes are build it distinguishes between hboxes in horizontal mode (group code 2) and those in vertical mode (group code 3).

What is different betwen the two is that in the vertical case `ins_node`, `mark_node` and `adjust_node` nodes (from `\insert`, `\mark` and `\vadjust`) migrate out of the box into the outer part.

They are collected in the `hpack` routine in the list starting at the pointer `adjust_head`.
Then when the group ends (group code 3) the head of this list is assigned to the tail of the list ending at `adjust_tail` and this is what you see in the above code happening.

See also §647.